# Nginx 1.25.3 on docker TLSv1 is not working

Tags: nginx, openssl

I have nginx 1.25.3 on docker, not the Alpine version. The underlying OS is Ubuntu 22.

When the TLS 1 protocols are configured like this:

```
ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
```

The TLSv1 is not working.

If using Openresty (the latest version) on the same OS, TLSv1 worked without any issue.

From this, my conjecture is this is not an OS issue, this is about the docker itself.

**Openresty uses `OpenSSL 1.1.1`, and the latest Nginx uses `OpenSSL 3.0.9`.**

After searching online, I found a few solutions:

A.Edit `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and add to it:

```
[openssl_init]
 providers = provider_sect
+ssl_conf = ssl_sect
+
+[ssl_sect]
+system_default = system_default_sect
+
+[system_default_sect]
+CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
```

B. add this `ssl_ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0;` to the nginx conf.

I tried both of the methods. I edited `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` inside and outside the docker, and I tried the B option, but none of that worked.

I read elsewhere that the Alpine version didn't compile in the TLSv1 support so I switched from the Alpine version to the regular `nginx:1.25.3` and still nothing worked (including after I tried the above in it and outside it).

How can I make it work? is there a specific version of the regular Nginx that works with this? Do I need to do something differently to make it work?

Comment: How are you testing TLSv1? Are docker and latest nginx a must?

Comment: May need to update the list of ciphers to use older ciphers available for 1.0.  https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.7&config=old&openssl=1.1.1k&guideline=5.7

Comment: @GChuf you can use OpenSSH to test this, in addition there is multiple online tools that do that. and yes, I want the lates, or at least the latest who support `http2` and TLS1

Comment: @GregAskew, my cipher list is updated, with the same list other releases of nginx works just fine